# Сылки по Яндекс карте?

Tags: jquery, yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

[image]

Есть три метки на картах Яндекс. Нужно, чтобы при клике на ссылку (блок верхнем углу) происходило перемещение карты в зону видимости этой метки. Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 0):

Можно при клике передавать адрес в ymaps.geocode
Пометил в коде **"Сюда адрес"**

p.s Передавать прямо в виде строки можно "Москва, ул...."

```js
function init() {
    var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
        center: [55.753994, 37.622093],
        zoom: 9
    });

    // Поиск координат центра Нижнего Новгорода.
    ymaps.geocode('Сюда адрес', {
        /**
         * Опции запроса
         * @see https://api.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/geocode.xml
         */
        // Сортировка результатов от центра окна карты.
        // boundedBy: myMap.getBounds(),
        // strictBounds: true,
        // Вместе с опцией boundedBy будет искать строго внутри области, указанной в boundedBy.
        // Если нужен только один результат, экономим трафик пользователей.
        results: 1
    }).then(function (res) {
            // Выбираем первый результат геокодирования.
            var firstGeoObject = res.geoObjects.get(0),
                // Координаты геообъекта.
                coords = firstGeoObject.geometry.getCoordinates(),
                // Область видимости геообъекта.
                bounds = firstGeoObject.properties.get('boundedBy');

            firstGeoObject.options.set('preset', 'islands#darkBlueDotIconWithCaption');
            // Получаем строку с адресом и выводим в иконке геообъекта.
            firstGeoObject.properties.set('iconCaption', firstGeoObject.getAddressLine());

            // Добавляем первый найденный геообъект на карту.
            myMap.geoObjects.add(firstGeoObject);
            // Масштабируем карту на область видимости геообъекта.
            myMap.setBounds(bounds, {
                // Проверяем наличие тайлов на данном масштабе.
                checkZoomRange: true
            });
        });
}
```